# making autogenerated module members visible to PyDev/PyLint static analysis

Tags: python, python-2.7, dynamic, pydev, static-analysis

If I am designing a Python module with dynamically-generated members, is there a way for me to help PyDev/PyLint out to give it some information? (rather than requiring end-users of the module to ignore errors or warnings)

Here's an example from [PyTables](https://github.com/PyTables/PyTables/blob/develop/tables/description.py#L246). I get errors about all the `UInt8Col`, `UInt16Col`, `UInt32Col`, etc. classes since they are invisible from static analysis, which I can suppress by adding `@UndefinedVariable` in a comment in my application code. But I'd like to know if there's a better way.

```
def _generate_col_classes():
    """Generate all column classes."""

    # Abstract classes are not in the class map.
    cprefixes = ['Int', 'UInt', 'Float', 'Time']
    for (kind, kdata) in atom.atom_map.iteritems():
        if hasattr(kdata, 'kind'):  # atom class: non-fixed item size
            atomclass = kdata
            cprefixes.append(atomclass.prefix())
        else:  # dictionary: fixed item size
            for atomclass in kdata.itervalues():
                cprefixes.append(atomclass.prefix())

    # Bottom-level complex classes are not in the type map, of course.
    # We still want the user to get the compatibility warning, though.
    cprefixes.extend(['Complex32', 'Complex64', 'Complex128'])
    if hasattr(atom, 'Complex192Atom'):
        cprefixes.append('Complex192')
    if hasattr(atom, 'Complex256Atom'):
        cprefixes.append('Complex256')

    for cprefix in cprefixes:
        newclass = Col._subclass_from_prefix(cprefix)
        yield newclass

# Create all column classes.
for _newclass in _generate_col_classes():
    exec('%s = _newclass' % _newclass.__name__)
del _newclass
```

Comment: PyDev/PyLint are probably targeting properties by source code line number. While you are generating these members dynamically, I would expect, PyDev/PyLint have no glue, what line in your code to point to.

Comment: Originally I thought, the problem is in use of "exec". There are methods how to create new classes without call of `exec`, e.g.: http://henry.precheur.org/python/Dynamically%20create%20a%20type%20with%20Python

Anyway, I do not think, this is resolving your problem.